# stat failed when updating filesystem

Tags: magento-2.1, cli, magento-community

When I try to run an update of the filesystem in Shell I get the following message:

> Warning: stat(): stat failed for
>   /data/web/magento2/vendor/magento/module-captch
>   a/view/frontend/web/js/view/checkout/defaultCaptcha.j in
>   /data/web/magento2/vend
>   or/magento/framework/Archive/Tar.php on line 324

What is wrong and what can I do to solve this problem?

I.m running Magento 2.1 CE

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same "Warning: stat(): stat failed for Tar.php on line 324"-error. For me it had to do with a broken symlink (different file).